# Can we use spring-security-saml2-service-provider in Quarkus

Tags: java, maven, compatibility, quarkus, spring-security-saml2

We are new to Quarkus and are using it to build a simple Service Provider for Single sign on via SAML protocol with Okta as IdentityProvider. Unfortunately Quarkus only supports OpenId Connect (we could not find any guide for SAML protocol). However, Spring already has implemented this in [spring-security-saml2-service-provider](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-saml2-service-provider) so we want to reuse this Spring component on Quarkus.

We only have 1 simple (spring rest) Controller on the project:

```java
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.quarkus.qute.CheckedTemplate;
import io.quarkus.qute.TemplateInstance;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public class GreetingController {

    @CheckedTemplate
    public static class Templates {
        public static native TemplateInstance hello();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public TemplateInstance index() {
        return Templates.hello();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/secured/hello")
    public String hello(@AuthenticationPrincipal Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal) {
        return "hello" + principal.getName();
    }
}
```

and some other configs for the OKTA under `application.properties`:

```
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.okta-saml.identityprovider.entity-id=<censored-value>
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.okta-saml.identityprovider.entity-id.verification.credentials.certificate-location="classpath:saml-certificate/okta.crt"
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.okta-saml.identityprovider.entity-id.singlesignon.url=<censored-value>
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.okta-saml.identityprovider.entity-id.singlesignon.sign-request=false
```

Unfortunately, when we try to run `mvn quarkus:dev` the system showed this error stacktrace:

```
2021-10-13 11:28:01,378 ERROR [io.qua.run.boo.StartupActionImpl] (Quarkus Main Thread) Error running Quarkus: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:65)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:119)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:29)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:390)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticatedPrincipal
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:445)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:405)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:455)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:405)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3191)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1904)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceBuilder.fromAnnotations(ResourceBuilder.java:908)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceBuilder.getRootResourceFromAnnotations(ResourceBuilder.java:878)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.<init>(POJOResourceFactory.java:41)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:92)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.registerResources(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:557)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.registration(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:475)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.startInternal(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.start(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:121)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.ResteasyStandaloneRecorder.staticInit(ResteasyStandaloneRecorder.java:36)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit345281060.deploy_0(ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit345281060.zig:991)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit345281060.deploy(ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit345281060.zig:40)
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:359)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticatedPrincipal
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:455)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:405)
        ... 37 more
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to use spring-security-saml2-service-provider on Quarkus? Or:
2. Is there any way we can make Quarkus uses SAML protocol for Single-sign-on?

here is our pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-quickstart</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.3.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-spring-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-elytron-security-properties-file</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-qute</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Spring Security providers in Quarkus will not work.

I suggest opening an issue on GitHub asking for SAML support in Quarkus

Answer (score 1):

I also asked this in Zulip chat, this is the answer I got from the Quarkus team:

> One option is to use quarkus-oidc and configure Keycloak (or other OIDC provider) to federate to your SAML provider; most good OIDC providers can do it

Comment: yes, I asked on their github project and received the similar response